# Is the boost::scoped thread automatically detached

Tags: c++, boost

Is the boost::scoped thread automatically detached or has to be detached manually.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/scoped_thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void thread()
{
    for (int i = 0; i != 10000; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
      boost::scoped_thread<> t{boost::thread{thread}};
      // Do I need t.detach() here
      // Some code from main function
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: A quick google search came up with the boost documentation page: "Scoped Threads are wrappers around a thread that allows the user to state what to do at destruction time. One of the common uses is to join the thread at destruction time so this is the default behavior."

Comment: @RichardHodges.. As a beginner with c++ and boost, I also came to know through documentation that it provides the automatic join behaviour.  But was confuse whether to detach or not.

Comment: I see. No, once the thread has been joined it is no longer joinable so does not need to be detached.

Comment: @RichardHodges A small query  if a function contains another function , is it a good idea to assign threading to both functions. Since those both function process a lot of for loop.

Comment: if they can reasonably run concurrently (and don't need to communicate) why not?

Answer (score 0):

Since this question doesn't have an answer, via [the scoped thread docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/thread/ScopedThreads.html),

> Scoped Threads are wrappers around a thread that allows the user to state what to do at destruction time. One of the common uses is to join the thread at destruction time so this is the default behavior.

The default behavior for plain old `boost::thread`s (and C++11's `std::thread` for that matter) is to call `std::terminate` on destruction if the object is joinable/detachable. In other words, when a regular thread object is going out of scope / being deleted, you must join or detach it first otherwise your program will crash. `scoped_thread`s automatically join on destruction.

To directly answer your question-- NO, by default, `scoped_thread` does not detach on destruction- it `join`s.